# Specify a page for pagination - Laravel 4

Tags: pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to "remember" the page the user was on as he browses through records so that when he returns to the list, he is returned to the page where he left off.

How do I change the "current page" value for paginator?

I've tried Input::set('page', $x); but there's no such function.
$_GET['page'] = $x; doesn't work too.

This the code:

```
$list = Publication::orderBy($this->data['sort_by'], $this->data['order_by']);

foreach ($this->data['filter_data'] AS $field => $value) {
    $list->where($field, 'LIKE', "%$value%");
}

$this->data['list'] = $list->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the page of the pagination environment through the DB connection.

```
DB::getPaginator()->setCurrentPage(2);
```

Not entirely sure but you might be able to go through your model with something like this.

```
Publication::getConnection()->setCurrentPage(2);
```

If the above isn't working (as it seems from your comment), then do it with an instance of `Publication`.

```
$publication = new Publication;

$publication->getConnection()->setCurrentPage(2);

$list = $publication->orderBy(...);
```

Comment: Both didn't work, I get a "Call to undefined method" error and a "Non-static method xxx::getConnection() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context" error

Comment: Woops, updated answer. That should've been `DB::getPaginator()->setCurrentPage();`

Comment: This worked for me as well. I was using `Paginator::make`. To be noted that you must place this instruction **before** `Paginator::make`. I was stuck there for a while, heh.

Comment: Your third example gives me: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setCurrentPage(), and the first two give errors as well.

Answer (score 21):

I looked at the API --- turns out this is much easier now in 2014.

All you have to do is set

```
Paginator::setCurrentPage(2);
```

any time before you call `->paginate()`, I believe, and it should override the page set (or not set) by `?page=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$pager->setCurrentPage(2);
```

Comment: I'm using Eloquent, but it seems that this method doesn't exist