# Laravel4 pagination on clicked page

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, pagination

I have a custom DB query in one of my model which uses laravels paginate and looks like

```
    public function getProducts(){
        $products = Product::join('product_specs', 'products.productid', '=', 'product_specs.product_id')
                             ->join('feeds_categories', 'product_specs.category', '=', 'feeds_categories.id')
                             ->where('feeds_categories.name', '=', 'Notebooks')
                             ->paginate(10);
             return $products;
    }
```

and I'm stucked how to call clicked page in this query. If I have a link like `http://example.com/api/products?name=lenovo&pageNumber=4&sortDir=asc&sortedBy=id`

how would I get products from page=4 ?

**Update**
sorry it's a duplicate [Specify a page for pagination - Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386641/specify-a-page-for-pagination-laravel-4/)

Answer (score 0):

`$products->appends(Request::query())` should work in updated 4.1/4.2 installations. `appends()` is documented in the pagination chapter of the official documentation.