# Laravel api pagination specify page

Tags: php, laravel

Am sending my request with perPage and page in the url. That is

```
url = users?page=0&perPage=10 //the get http url
```

So i would like to paginate my model request like and specify both page and perPage

```
User::paginate()
```

So looking in the docs i see i can add perPage but i cant see how to add the page. so from [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination) i see you can add the perPage like

```
User::paginate($request->get('perPage')) //perPage from url request
```

But now how do i add the page parameter to the paginate, such that i can specify page  value like 0

HOw do i proceed?

I have also checked on [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386641/specify-a-page-for-pagination-laravel-4) but it doesnt show how to set it in an eloquent model paginate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `paginate` method in [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L704) has the following signature:

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
```

As long as you have a `page=n` (n for number > 0, i.e: page=2) in your url (query string), you don't need the page number to be passed in `paginate` method. In case you want then, you may do it using something like the following:

```
$users = User::paginate(
    10, // per page (may be get it from request)
    ['*'], // columns to select from table (default *, means all fields)
    'page', // page name that holds the page number in the query string
    10 // current page, default 1
);
```

FYI,  `Laravel` resolves the current page using [Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator:: resolveCurrentPage](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L401) method which (resolver) was set in [Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider:: currentPageResolver](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Pagination/PaginationServiceProvider.php#L40) method when registering the service provider.

In case you don't know, you can also omit the `perPage` because by default `Laravel` chunks by `15` records and it's set up in the base model and you can override it in your model using:

```
protected $perPage = 10;
```

So, you can just use `User::paginate()` which will give you `10` items/perPage.

*Note: The api links are given for `5.6` but it's same in higher versions in this case (AFAIK).*

Answer (score 2):

From official documentation

```
the current page is detected by the value of the page query string argument on the HTTP request.
```

Laravel handle it automatically. So you don't need do something.

Answer (score 1):

Use `->appends()` method

```
$users = User::paginate($request->get('perPage')); 
$users->appends($request->all());
```